# Agora API for c# .Net Maui

Tags: agora.io

I am looking at integration of agora realtime video and audio calls within a mobile application example.

We are using .Net Maui Preview which uses .NET 6 to deploy a blazor app to an android device.

Is there anyway of integrating agora with this? some sort of nuget package or a way to compile a dll or nuget package to be used ?

Comment: Did you have any luck finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Agora offers an iOS and Android SDK. From what I can tell there's no way to include Kotlin/Swift code in a Blazor application, which would mean you're out of luck.
As an alternative maybe you can take a look at the Agora Flutter/React Native SDKs if you're building a cross platform app.